# Unable to pull image from gcr.io

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've been trying to run the [Hello Node tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-node) for a couple of days now and I finally figured out what was preventing me from seeing the app, but I'm not sure why this is happening.

I looked at the Kubernetes events tab and kept seeing this error.

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/simpleapp-1073/hello-node": Error: image simpleapp-1073/hello-node:latest not found
```

`simpleapp-1073` is my `PROJECT_ID`

When I pushed the docker image to the public docker hub and pointed my image attribute to that, everything finally started working.

Is there some trick to getting the private container registry working?

Comment: is your Kubernetes cluster running in the project "simpleapp-1073" as well?

Comment: The tutorial mentions the kubernetes master is run by Google Container Engine so I'm not sure how to answer that. The instance where the worker node is running is in simpleapp-1073

Comment: Did you delete your cluster?

Comment: Yes, I've been deleting and recreating the cluster to avoid charges since it's just a test app. How could that affect this? I only completed the "before you begin" section once, if that helps. https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/before-you-begin

Comment: There is one step on the before you begin section that asks you to run "gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME" I'm pretty sure I re-ran this after creating a new cluster, even though it was named the same thing, "hello-world". Could this effect the kubernetes node pulling the image from gci.io?

Comment: When you created your image did you also push a latest tag to gcr.io?

Comment: I've been trying a few things with the image, changing the bound IP address of the server and listen port. Every time I updated the image I would build and push. I can't remember if I tagged it.

Comment: Just tried this again today. Tagged and pushed the container and still get the same error message. Really odd.

Comment: Tried setting up a new container cluster with `--scopes storage-full` but that didn't  help either. FWIW, ssh'ing into the VM and trying `docker pull gcr.io/simpleapp-1073/hello-node` gives me the same error as above.

Comment: I'm able to confirm this issue is fixed when I make the images in the `artifacts.simpleapp-1073.xxxxx` bucket, the node is then able to pull the image. Really weird that this is happening and essentially defeats the purpose of a private registry, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an entirely new project and tried the steps in the [Hello Node tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-node) and everything worked. The `simpleapp-1073` I was trying to use before was created a long time ago, probably about a year ago. Perhaps that had some affects on this issue. I'm happy with this solution since I was just trying to get the tutorial up and running.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue. Authentication of local docker with Google registry helped:

```
gcloud docker -a
```

and then

```
sudo docker pull gcr.io/simpleapp-1073/hello-node
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the only thing that worked was creating an entirely new project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was getting an ImagePullBackOff
status on my Pod.

My fix was to re-create the kubernetes cluster and try to deploy again and everything worked.

I think something got messed up as the original-service account I used when creating the cluster got deleted and a new one was created with the same name, so perhaps there was a hidden ID attached to the old cluster still that was trying to use a service account that didn't exist anymore.

Comment: I created both original and replacement service accounts through the IAM web console / interface